# What's wrong with this PDO Query?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to learn how to convert my database queries to PDO. Someone told me to convert one of my queries as follows...

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT P.URL, P.Title, P.Subtitle, P.MetaTitle, P.MetaDesc, P.KW, P.Site, P.Live, PB.Common, PB.First, PB.Middle, PB.Last, PB.Prefix, PB.Suffix, PB.Alpha, PB.Born, PB.Died, PB.Birth_Place, PB.Death_Place, PB.Nationality, PC.URL, PC.Class, Brf.URL, Brf.Site, Brf.Brief, ART.Article PXA
FROM people P
LEFT JOIN people_1_bio PB ON PB.URL = P.URL
LEFT JOIN people_1_class PC ON PC.URL = P.URL
LEFT JOIN people_briefs Brf ON Brf.URL = P.URL
LEFT JOIN people_articles_px ART ON ART.URL = P.URL
WHERE P.Site = 'PX' AND Brf.Site  = 'PX' AND PB.Alpha LIKE ? AND Brf.Brief !='' AND PC.URL = P.URL AND P.Live = 1
GROUP BY P.URL ORDER BY P.N");
$stmt->execute(array($MyURL.'%'));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

It's more user friendly than most of the examples I see in tutorials - but it doesn't work. It throws two error messages:

Notice: Undefined variable: db in /Users/... on line 118

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /Users/... on line 118

They correspond to this line...

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("ELECT P.URL, P.Title, P.Subtitle, P.MetaTitle, P.MetaDesc, P.KW, P.Site, P.Live,
```

---

I've found this same question asked on several StackOverflow discussions, but I don't understand the answers. One discussion says you have to create a "$db object" using this example:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database")
```

However, I'm using MySQL. I tried changing mysqli to mysql, but it doesn't work.

Another discussion says I need to paste the following above my query:

```
function confirmIPAddress($value) {
  global $db
```

To make it work, I have to add a semi-colon at the end, then put a closing bracket after my query. But it doesn't work. I thought PDO was supposed to be user friendly, but it doesn't even compare to the old method.

This was my original query:

```
$res = mysql_query ("SELECT P.URL, P.Title, P.Subtitle, P.MetaTitle, P.MetaDesc, P.KW, P.Site, P.Live, PB.Common, PB.First, PB.Middle, PB.Last, PB.Prefix, PB.Suffix, PB.Alpha, PB.Born, PB.Died, PB.Birth_Place, PB.Death_Place, PB.Nationality, PC.URL, group_concat(PC.Class), Brf.URL, Brf.Site, Brf.Brief, ART.Article PXA
FROM people P
LEFT JOIN people_1_bio PB ON PB.URL = P.URL
LEFT JOIN people_1_class PC ON PC.URL = P.URL
LEFT JOIN people_briefs Brf ON Brf.URL = P.URL
LEFT JOIN people_articles_px ART ON ART.URL = P.URL
WHERE P.Site = 'PX' AND Brf.Site  = 'PX' AND PB.Alpha LIKE '$MyURL%' AND Brf.Brief !='' AND PC.URL = P.URL AND P.Live = 1
GROUP BY P.URL ORDER BY P.N") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: Is the missing S on `$stmt = $db->prepare("ELEC` a typo in the question only or is it in your code too?

Comment: So please post the code as you have it, currently surrounding the query. The error message implies that `$db` is not in scope, if this is occurring inside a function, wherein you must either pass `$db` to the function as a parameter (preferred) or access it globally (not preferred)

Comment: You need to declare $db as new PDO

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an existing database connection it would be best to pass it into your function, i.e.:

```
function confirmIPAddress(PDO $db, $value) 
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare('..');
    // ...
```

When called:

```
confirmIPAddress($db, $value);
```